# Hungarian Algorithm using Maximum Bipartite Matching for Assignment

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to understand the O(N^4) explanation for the assignment problem by reading the topcoder article [1] . Specifically, i am unable to comprehend how the default O(N^5) procedure can be converted to O(N^4). Please read below for details:

Assume for the assignment problem, a complete bipartite graph of N vertices in both sets of vertices, and a edge cost from vertex i to vertex j, denoted by cost[i][j] that is say, integral, non-negative. We are trying to minimize the overall sum of weights of the perfect matching (assuming there is one)

Quoting the O(n^4) algorithm from [1]

```
Step 0)
    A. For each vertex from left Set (workers) find the minimal outgoing edge and subtract its weight from all weights connected with this vertex. This will introduce 0-weight edges (at least one).
    B. Apply the same procedure for the vertices in the right Set (jobs).

Step 1)
    A. Find the maximum matching using only 0-weight edges (for this purpose you can use max-flow algorithm, augmenting path algorithm, etc.).
    B. If it is perfect, then the problem is solved. Otherwise find the minimum vertex cover V (for the subgraph with 0-weight edges only), the best way to do this is to use Konig’s graph theorem.

Step 2) 
    Let delta = min(cost[i][j]) for i not belonging to vertex cover, and j not belonging to vertex cover.
    Then, modify the cost matrix as follows:
        cost[i][j] = cost[i][j] - delta   for i not belonging to vertex cover, and j not belonging to vertex cover.
        cost[i][j] = cost[i][j] + delta   for i belonging to vertex cover, and j belonging to vertex cover.
        cost[i][j] = cost[i][j]           otherwise

Step 3) 
    Repeat Step 1) until problem is solved
```

I understand that the above algorithm is O(n^5) if implemented as-is, since the maximum matching on a bipartite graph takes O(n^3) if we use, say, breadth first search, and there are O(n^2) iterations of the overall algorithm since each edge becomes 0 in an iteration.

But, [1] also mentions:

> finding the maximum matching in step 1 on each iteration will cause the algorithm to become O(n^5). In order to avoid this, on each step we can just modify the matching from the previous step, which only takes O(n^2) operations, making the overall algorithm O(n^4)

This is the part i do not understand. How do we modify the matching from the previous epoch, thereby taking only O(N^2) operations, instead of the normal O(N^3) iterations for maximum bipartite matching?

I referred [2] as well, but in that solution as well, there is only a comment that says:

> // to make O(n^4), start from previous solution

I fail to understand how to convert the O(N^5) to O(N^4), and what exactly starting from previous solution mean?
Can someone explain using the algorithm referenced in [1], how to modify it to run in O(N^4)? Pseudo-code would be most welcome.

[1] https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/assignment-problem-and-hungarian-algorithm/

[2] http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/65reductions/Hungarian.java

Thanks in Advance.